# QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

First, I use Windows 7-64 bit with PyQwt5.2.0, PyQt4.5.4, NumPy1.3.0, python2.6.2 32-bit for compatibility reasons.

While runnning my script this appears:

```
QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice
```

Surfing the net, looking for some way to fix it, I got that `QWidget` inherits `QObject` and `QPaintDevice` (and it is inherited bye almost every object I use), and `QMainWindow` inherits `QWidget`. I also got that some static function is trying to use some class, but I do not really understand what it means.

If someone could please explain this, I would really appreciate it.

PS: Sorry for any translation mistakes.

Comment: As the error said, you are not allowed to create a QWidget (or any QPaintDevice) before the QApplication is created. But without the code that creates the problem, I don't see how we can help beside repeating the error message ...

Comment: probably, while I was trying to fix it I messed up

Comment: This question should likely be deleted as the O.P. posted his code to a temporary pastebin (which no longer exists). This really isn't a useful question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the code, the error is due to line 102. There, while the module is loaded, you create a `QWidget` (more precisely a `QMainWindow`). And this happens **before** the `QApplication` is created.

Also, I don't know why you have this start variable there, as it doesn't seem to be used.

If you want to create it with the `HelloBegin` object, move it in the `__init__` method.

**Edit:**

If you want to display a splash screen while your modules are loading, you need the application to be started by a small, lightweight, module. In this module, you will:

1. Create the QApplication
2. Open your splash screen / message box
3. Only then load the other modules

For everything to work smoothly, I would import the modules in a separate function, and use a small trick to make sure it's started only once the GUI is ready. The code will look like this:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer
def startApp():
    import m1
    import m2
    wnd = createWindow()
    wnd.show()
import sys
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
splash = createSplashScreen()
splash.show()
QTimer.singleShot(1, startApp) # call startApp only after the GUI is ready
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

where `createSplashScreen` is the function that creates your splash screen

Comment: the main idea was to start the app with a messagebox asking the way to show (fullscreen or normal mode) tha page and maybe a splashcreen. Anyway, I solved trying as you told
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @bomba If my solution worked, I would appreciate that you accept it

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the error while running *unittest*.

```
QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget
```

The solution was constructing the QApplication for every test method.

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
```