# PyQt5 TableView kills kernal

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

So, Im currently taking just limited data from a ZeroMQ Messaging system appending it all to a Dataframe and then turning the Dataframe into a pandas model with code I acquired from someone on stack. Then running that model through a PyQt5 Tableview.

Every time I run the tableview code, after converting my Dataframe to a model for Tableview the kernal just dies. I tried to at least handle a exception but it wont even raise a runtimeerror that is super general. It just dies every time....

For the purpose of the test im using a CSV with data to try to get this into a workable model. You can use any csv or data you have on your end to test this as theres no hard coded formatting.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import pandas as pd


class PandasModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):     
    def __init__(self, df = pd.DataFrame(), parent=None): 
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self._df = df

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            try:
                return self._df.columns.tolist()[section]
            except (IndexError, ):
                return QtCore.QVariant()
        elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
            try:
                # return self.df.index.tolist()
                return self._df.index.tolist()[section]
            except (IndexError, ):
                return QtCore.QVariant()

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        return QtCore.QVariant(str(self._df.ix[index.row(), index.column()]))

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        row = self._df.index[index.row()]
        col = self._df.columns[index.column()]
        if hasattr(value, 'toPyObject'):
            # PyQt4 gets a QVariant
            value = value.toPyObject()
        else:
            # PySide gets an unicode
            dtype = self._df[col].dtype
            if dtype != object:
                value = None if value == '' else dtype.type(value)
        self._df.set_value(row, col, value)
        return True

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): 
        return len(self._df.index)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): 
        return len(self._df.columns)

    def sort(self, column, order):
        colname = self._df.columns.tolist()[column]
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self._df.sort_values(colname, ascending= order == QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder, inplace=True)
        self._df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
        self.layoutChanged.emit()   


def createview(title, model):
    try:
        view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        view.setWindowview
    except:
        raise RuntimeError("I know python!")


if __name__=="__main__":
    df=pd.read_csv("C:\Excel Sheets\Test_CSV_6-18-18.csv")
    model = PandasModel(df)
    createview("Model", model)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452937/qwidget-must-construct-a-qapplication-before-a-qpaintdevice)

Comment: Use: `def createview(title, model):
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    view.setWindowTitle(title)
    view.setModel(model)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())`

Comment: Oh my goodness. You are amazing. Thank you

Comment: I recommend you read a PyQt tutorial before continuing, your problem indicates that you do not know anything about PyQt.

Comment: You are partially correct. Im not sure why I missed the whole view.show() but the sys.exit(app.exe_()) i didnt know. Im going to hop on that tutorial