# PySide 6 create a class as a QLabel object not working

Tags: pyside6, qlabel

I'm trying to make a custom QLabel class but I always got an error code -1073740791. Any idea how to make it work? Coding on PyCharm. Thanks

Code:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import*
class IconLabel(QLabel):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

lab = IconLabel()
```

Try to make a custom QLabel object to display specific icon on demand into it, but can't initiate the object before adding the function. Error code without details or info from the web.

Comment: If you run it in the terminal you'll probably get a more useful error message. Otherwise, make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There's nothing wrong with the code you're currently showing.

Comment: Of course it's appening when I try to create the object with code: lab = IconLabel()  that's exactly the code making an error.  I'll try from the terminal thanks

Comment: Terminal answer is: "QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget" not sure how to do it...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452937/qwidget-must-construct-a-qapplication-before-a-qpaintdevice)

Answer (score 0):

QWidgets need a [QApplication](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qapplication.html) running.

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import*

class IconLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setText('hello')


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
lab = IconLabel()
lab.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

If you look at other examples you'll see that they all have similar lines at the bottom. It's just a bit of boilerplate code to run a Qt app.

Comment: @mahkitah that's not "boilerplate".

Answer (score -2):

Ok so to init a QLabel you need to pass a widget parent to it and create a QApplication before it, then you declare the previous widget as parent:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import*                                                                                                  
class IconLabel(QLabel):

    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__(parent=widget)                                                                                 

import sys                                                                                                                  
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QWidget()
lab = IconLabel(widget)
```

Thanks @mahkitah

Comment: This has nothing to do with your problem, and you absolutely do **not** need a parent to create a QLabel (or any other widget).

Comment: Yes it was explained by mahkitah previously, or you have another explanation? @musicamante

Comment: The point is that mahkitah has already and correctly answered, there is no point in adding another answer that also makes invalid statements. Please take your time to follow the [tour] (remember, StackOverflow is not a forum) and read [answer].